# libVLC Нужно ли вручную загружать библиотеки?

Tags: c++, vlc

Использую VLC SDK со статическими библиотеками, подгружаю вручную библиотеки `libvlc.dll`, `libvlccore.dll`, но когда загружаю `libvlc.dll` его `HMODULE` всегда равен нулю.

Вот теперь я в замешательстве, нужно ли его вообще грузить вручную?

Вывод в консольное окно дебага.

```
LoadLibrary: libvlccore.dll
libvlc_core: 00500000
LoadLibrary: libvlc.dll
libvlc: 00000000
Framework: Create
Framework: Initialize
Framework: CreateAWWindow
Framework: Run
[06df0cfc] core vout display error: Failed to set on top
```

Comment: Блин, спасибо, понял что они сами грузятся. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Понял что не надо грузить, попробовал получить `HMODULE` при запуске фреймворка, перед инициализацией `libvlc`, увидел следующее:

```
libvlc.dll: 69E50000
libvlccore.dll 69A00000
Framework: Create
Framework: Initialize
Framework: CreateAWWindow
Framework: Run
[06ace8a4] core vout display error: Failed to set on top
```